# Windows Biometric Framework for fingerprint device

Tags: c++, wdk, umdf, wbf, wbdi

We have our fingerprint device which is working properly as USB device.

Data capturing works fine with our proprietary application.

Currently we are using custom vendor USB class for driver development.

When we plug this device, this device is listed in "Universial Serial Bus Controller" catagories in Windows Device Manager.

We want to use Windows Biometric Framework for the same device to achieve Windows Biometric login.

I understand that, we need to write WBDI compitible driver but I have query related to fingerprint device hardware.

We are targeting Windows 7 and later operating systems.

Will there be any changes required in hardware to work with WBDI driver ?